# Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton

Tags: android, image, text, button

I'm trying to have an image (as the background) on a button and add dynamically, depending on what's happening during run-time, some text above/over the image.

If I use `ImageButton` I don't even have the possibility to add text.
If I use `Button` I can add text but only define an image with `android:drawableBottom` and similar XML attributes as defined [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom).

However these attributes only combine text & image in x- and y-dimensions, meaning I can draw an image around my text, but not below/under my text (with the z-axis defined as coming out of the display).

Any suggestions on how to do this? One idea would be to either extend `Button` or `ImageButton` and override the `draw()`-method. But with my current level of knowledge I don't really know how to do this (2D rendering). Maybe someone with more experience knows a solution or at least some pointers to start?

Comment: use 9Patch, smart solution

Comment: hi  @Charuක  please check this if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse

Comment: Best way is use `CardView` >> Just put `LinearLayout` inside `CardView`, set `image` as a background of `LinearLayout` and use `textView` inside in this `LinearLayout` . For more Details **check out this** > https://stackoverflow.com/a/65172123/12750160 . Thanks, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You can call `setBackground()` on a `Button` to set the background of the button.

Any text will appear above the background.

If you are looking for something similar in xml there is:
`android:background` attribute which works the same way.

Comment: If you go this route, you do not want to just use a simple drawable for the background. Use a StateListDrawable (usually via <selector> XML file in res/drawable/), so you can define backgrounds for the various states (normal, pressed, focused, disabled, etc.).

Comment: Agree with you, look for this question and my answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533038/android-specify-two-different-images-for-togglebutton-using-xml

Comment: How stupid. How could I have missed that in the documentation. Thanks for the quick answer and also the hint with the <selector>. That's something I definitely want to implement in the future.

Comment: It doesn't work right on ICS 4.0+ versions, the image stretches.
I was using a TextView with a background.

Answer (score 635):

**For users who just want to put Background, Icon-Image and Text in one** `Button` from different files: Set on a `Button` background, drawableTop/Bottom/Rigth/Left and *padding* attributes.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_btn_test"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon_test"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
        android:paddingTop="32sp"
        android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
        android:text="this is text"></Button>
```

For more sophisticated arrangement you also can use `RelativeLayout` (or any other layout) and make it clickable.

**Tutorial:** Great tutorial that covers both cases: http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/8/Creating-Android-button-with-image-and-text-using-relative-layout.aspx

Comment: To do this programmatically use `b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBound(null,R.drawable.home_icon_test,null,null)` instead of `android:drawableTop` and `b.setPadding(0,32,0,0)` instead of `android:paddingTop`.

Comment: Using a layout as a button is actually a quite flexible approach.

Comment: Just replace null with 0 if you are using resource ids for your drawables

Comment: How can I scale the backgournd image to fit the button?

Comment: @Stallman There is a xml-based and code-based solution for scaling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223936/how-can-i-scale-the-background-of-a-button

Comment: is there an XML way to have different the image when pressed?

Comment: @EnesBattal yes, assign it to a StateListDrawable http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: @OneWorld, I tried but it didn't work. It shows no images. I asked this question in SO, if you have an answer can you post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264654/android-button-with-text-with-different-images-for-enabled-and-pressed

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin Your comment is five years old and has 61 helpful votes, but I'm having problems with it. To start with the method name should be setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(), with "s" at the end, shouldn't it? And after I make that change it still doesn't work for me unless I change the three "null" arguments to "0", so it invokes the version of the method that takes four int arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to increase the size if the icon without modifing the original icon size?

Answer (score 359):

There's a much better solution for this problem.

Just take a normal `Button` and use the `drawableLeft` and the `gravity` attributes.

```
<Button
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_btn_icon"
  android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
```

This way you get a button which displays a icon in the left side of the button and the text at the right site of the icon *vertical centered*.

Comment: A problem occurs with this solution if you chose to have a background color on the button (which is likely in this case). Then there will be no graphical response to click or selection. You can write a selector to handle this, but then you will not get the phones default colors.

Comment: Just wanted to add that _Drawable padding_ property is very useful if this solution is used.

Comment: Is there a way to set height & width for drawable icon in xml?

Comment: This is a great solution and is also officially endorsed on the Android developer site: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html

Comment: if the button is large and the text is variable long, than looks like ugly: icon at most left and text somewhere in middle

Comment: @user529543 you can give the text alignment. that fixes this problem

Comment: An image is drawn from left, no matter what is a gravity and padding.

Comment: @CoolMind - if you use drawableRight it's on the right side. The gravity stuff is for the text alignment.

Answer (score 68):

[image]

```
     <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/home_button"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:drawablePadding="6dp"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:text="AndroidDhina"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: A simple and wrong solution. Only for left aligning.

Comment: @ CoolMind I am explaining only for above image i have attached ..if you want right align use drawableRight

Comment: I wasn't even thinking of doing this until I read this answer. This works like a charm!

Answer (score 64):

Just use a LinearLayout and pretend it's a `Button` - setting `background` and *clickable* is the key:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Do stuff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to add clicked effect?

Comment: Best answer, this way you manage 100% of the look and feel and you don't have to stick the icon to a border.

Comment: frankish, add `android:onClick` to your view

Comment: The only real solution. What a hassle !

Answer (score 46):

just replace

```
android:background="@drawable/icon"
```

with

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/[your background image here]"
```

izz a pretty good trick.. ;)

Answer (score 22):

I took a different approach from the ones stated here, and it is working really well, so I wanted to share it.

I'm using a Style to create a custom button with image at the left and text at the center-right. Just follow the 4 "easy steps" below:

I. Create your 9 patches using at least 3 different PNG files and the tool you have at: /YOUR_OWN_PATH/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/./draw9patch. After this you should have:

button_normal.9.png, button_focused.9.png and button_pressed.9.png

Then download or create a 24x24 PNG icon.

ic_your_icon.png

Save all in the drawable/ folder on your Android project.

II. Create a XML file called button_selector.xml in your project under the drawable/ folder. The states should be like this:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
```

III. Go to the values/ folder and open or create the styles.xml file and create the following XML code:

```
<style name="ButtonNormalText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor" >@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize" >12dip</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
    <item name="android:height" >44dip</item>
    <item name="android:background" >@drawable/button_selector</item>
    <item name="android:focusable" >true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable" >true</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonNormalTextWithIcon" parent="ButtonNormalText">
    <item name="android:drawableLeft" >@drawable/ic_your_icon</item>
</style>
```

ButtonNormalTextWithIcon is a "child style" because it is extending ButtonNormalText (the "parent style").

Note that changing the drawableLeft in the ButtonNormalTextWithIcon style, to drawableRight,  drawableTop or drawableBottom you can place the icon in other position with respect to the text.

IV. Go to the layout/ folder where you have your XML for the UI and go to the Button where you want to apply the style and make it look like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit" 
android:text="@string/button_submit" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
style="@style/ButtonNormalTextWithIcon" ></Button>
```

And... voilà! You got your button with an image at the left side.

For me, this is the better way to do it! because doing it this way you can manage the text size of the button separately from the icon you want to display and use the same background drawable for several buttons with different icons respecting the Android UI Guidelines using styles.

You can also create a theme for your App and add the "parent style" to it so all the buttons look the same, and apply the "child style" with the icon only where you need it.

Comment: Good work. I was using a FrameLayout view approach with an ImageView and TextView inside, but this approach is nicer.

Comment: Awesome approach. The facebook SDK (version 3) takes the same approach for the login button

Answer (score 14):

### Important Update

> Don't use normal `android:drawableLeft` etc... with vector drawables, else it
>   will **crash** in **lower API versions**. (I have faced it in live app)

#### For vector drawable

If you are using vector drawable, then you must

- Have you migrated to AndroidX? if not you must migrate to AndroidX first. It is very simple, see [what is androidx, and how to migrate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517772/6891563)
- It was released in version [`1.1.0-alpha01`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha01), so appcompat version should be at least `1.1.0-alpha01`. Current latest version is `1.1.0-alpha02`, use latest versions for better reliability, see release notes - [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#1.1.0-alpha02).

  > `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'`
- Use `AppCompatTextView`/`AppCompatButton`/`AppCompatEditText`
- Use `app:drawableLeftCompat`, `app:drawableTopCompat`, `app:drawableRightCompat`, `app:drawableBottomCompat`, `app:drawableStartCompat` and `app:drawableEndCompat`

#### For regular drawable

If you don't need vector drawable, then you can

- use `android:drawableLeft`, `android:drawableRight`, `android:drawableBottom`, `android:drawableTop`
- You can use either regular `TextView`, `Button` & `EditText` or `AppCompat` classes.

You can achieve **Output** like below -

[image: output]

Comment: I'm using `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace and don't see those app compat things.

Comment: @Dale your namespace is correct, I have updated my answer, see `For vector drawable` point again.

Comment: @Khemraj How you are centering both drawable and text in the single view(either a TextView or Button or something else) as displayed in the image you attached?

Answer (score 13):

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/imeageTextBtn" 
        android:layout_width="240dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Side Icon With Text Button"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_side_icon"         
        />
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `drawableTop` (also `drawableLeft`, etc) for the image and set text below the image by adding the `gravity` `left|center_vertical`

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_video"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/videos"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onClickFragment"
            android:text="Videos"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 12):

[MaterialButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/) has support for setting an icon and aligning it to the text:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My button"
        app:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        />
```

`app:iconGravity` can also be to `start` / `end` if you want to align the icon to the button instead of the text inside it.

---

Since version 1.5.0-beta01, `app:iconGravity` can also be `top` / `textTop` ([commit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/b39845a452f547d5844996074ac9aabe911d637f))

[image: MaterialButton with iconGravity top]

Answer (score 7):

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/groups_button_bg"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Groups"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/[image]" />


android:drawableLeft
android:drawableRight
android:drawableBottom
android:drawableTop
```

http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/04/create-a-button-with-an-image-and-text-android/

Answer (score 7):

Probably my solution will suit for a lot of users, I hope so.

What I am suggesting it is making TextView with your style. It works for me perfectly, and has got all features, like a button.

First of all lets make button style, which you can use everywhere...I am creating button_with_hover.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#8dbab3" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#48608F" android:endColor="#48608F"  />
        </shape>

        <!--#284682;-->
        <!--border-color: #223b6f;-->
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#284682" />
            <solid android:color="#284682"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/ControlColors" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/ControlColors" android:endColor="@color/ControlColors" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Secondly, 
Lets create a textview button.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="@drawable/button_with_hover"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:text="Golden Gate" />
```

And this is a result. Then style your custom button with any colors or any other properties and margins. Good luck

[image]

Comment: Although I am yet to test your code as approach seems to be correct, but I don't understand the reason of having hover effect in a mobile app.

Comment: I have created hover effect for my app, and during that app build I needed hover effect. But it is up to you:) You can delete hover effect if it is not necessary.

Comment: I have voted up your answer as it is a very good approach. My only point is on a mobile interface how can you hover?

Comment: Oo...I see now.. :D Yeap, you are right. It is impossible. That hover effect is mostly for pressing effect. Just incorrect name for xml class

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me perfectly

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/choosePhotosView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_button_bg_rev_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/choose_photo"/>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/choose_photos_tv"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried your code.. it works but the main problem of your code if you have set of buttons, with different text sizes in each button. Your layout will be shifted. So each  picture position of the button will be in a different place. While it should be straight in the center. 

This is what happens with button.

Answer (score 3):

To combine `Button` and `drawableTop` and still get the click response, you can use button style `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless` to make it transparent.

[image]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/settings"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_settings_24"
    android:drawableTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/settings"
    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/myButton" 
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Image Button"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/myimage"         
    />
```

Or you can programmatically:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
myButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, drawable, null, null);//to the Top of the Button
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/reset_all"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_med"
                    android:text="Reset all"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/undo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_med"
                    android:text="Undo"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

in that i have put an image as `background` and also added text..!

Answer (score 0):

## Make a fake button.

It's really the only way

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fake_button"

        android:layout_width=" .. "
        android:layout_height=" .. "

        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="tappedNext">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fake_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/your_amazing_drawable" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fake_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Next"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ .. "
            android:textColor="@color/ .. "
            android:textSize=" .. " />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/temp"
        />
```

Comment: This is not a right answer because Image view doesnt suppport text