# What kind of Button can toggle/change states in Android?

Tags: android, button, state

So I have an image button and I want to have two states on it. It will work like a bookmark button which has two states. If the user presses the button then it changes the image and if it re-presses the button then I want the original image back.

Is that possible? Is there an easier way using another type of button?
Thank you

Comment: Friendly advice: Add some more details to your question. Especially, the title is a bit confusing.

Comment: Try using your own custom css for that button?

Comment: sorry everyone.. Modified the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the topic to :"What kind of Button can toggle/change states?"

Seems like you need `ToggleBotton`

```
<ToggleButton                  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@color/button_colors"
        android:button="@null"
        android:textOff="@null"
        android:textOn="@null" />
```

And this xml defines the colors/images of the button at rest/pressed states, put it in `res/color/button_colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_rest"/>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_on" />    
</selector>
```

Comment: thank you. So after that I just need to attach a listener and set the actions.. I can get the state of the button rigth? and depending on that I can perform actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use regular buttons also. First make a selector XML file in the res/drawable directory. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/selectedimage"/>

<item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/notselectedimage"/>

</selector>
```

In the button definition in the layout xml, you just add this attribute:

```
android:background="@drawable/myselectorxmlfile"
```

And then you programmatically set the selected states yourself (in a onClickListener) and the button images will change background state.

```
button.setSelected(true) // or false;
```

Answer (score 0):

These links might help you..
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html
and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use Toggle Button and hope it'll solve your issue.
Just have a look at a simple xml code of it:

```
<ToggleButton
              android:id="@+id/tglbtn"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textOn="ON"
              android:textOff="OFF"
              />
```

And Just check the answer given here in this link:
[Android: Specify two different images for togglebutton using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533038/android-specify-two-different-images-for-togglebutton-using-xml)

Also,
I've posted a simple tutorial about Toggle Button. Just have a look at my humble blog if you find it helpful. Here is link: http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/03/10/toggle-button-in-android/