# ImageButton return blank

Tags: android, imagebutton

i'm new here and i'm trying to make an ImageButton switch state.

Here's my ImageButton fully functional :

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:onClick="sendEmailIntent"
    android:src="@drawable/email_96" />
```

When i want to use another image when the button is pressed i use this btn_custom_email.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@+drawable/email_96.png" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@+drawable/email_pressed_96.png" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@+drawable/email_pressed_96.png" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@+drawable/email_96.png" android:state_enabled="true"/>
```

And change android:src="@drawable/email_96" by android:src="@drawable/btn_custom_email" for my ImageButton. But then my button turn blank with no error.

It's been a few hours i've been looking for help. I tried :

- [Refrencing a selector drawable from a style results blank imagebutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751067/refrencing-a-selector-drawable-from-a-style-results-blank-imagebutton)
- [What kind of Button can toggle/change states in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403349/what-kind-of-button-can-toggle-change-states-in-android)
- [Android: Specify two different images for togglebutton using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533038/android-specify-two-different-images-for-togglebutton-using-xml)

and many more but couln't find why i've got a blank button. Thank you for your time. Have a good night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
 android:drawable="@+drawable/email_96.png"
```

Should be:

```
 android:drawable="@drawable/email_96"
```

(no + and no .png)

Same for all 4 lines

Comment: Thank you very much ! My button is back but it's not working so i've got still work to do. Have a nice day.

Comment: This is another question... make sure you set your listener either in xml or in java code. Have a good day too!