# How to style ToggleButton so that the background color is WHITE?

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, togglebutton

I have tried the following

```
View view = (View) findViewById (id);
view.setBackgroundColor (Color.WHITE);
```

The above destroys the property of the ToggleButton. I can no longer make out if it is TextView or ToggleButton. Clicking the button produces onClick but the UI change to show the selected bar is absent.

```
ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) findViewById (id);
btn.setBackgroundColor (Color.WHITE);
```

This also produces the same error. Using XML styling also causes the same error. I am using Android Studio v1.0.2 and the target is a lollipop emulator. I tried the same thing in 4.4.4 mobile. I see the same behavior.

I don't want to use images. Kindly don't suggest that to me. I have gone through the threads that are available in stackoverflow - nothing works for me.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you give more detail or a sketch of what you want the toggle button to look like in each state (on/off)? You will need to create a selector and probably drawables for each state. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1533412/2832027

Comment: Thanks for the link. The thread talks about using images for check/uncheck events. I dont want to do that. But just style the toggle button so that the button color is white. Everything else remains the same. Any idea if that is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this as an xml file in drawables that you want as the background for the toggle button. You need to add the various colors to a color file in res/values. See: https://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRouter/res/values/colors.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item android:top="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_pressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_checked" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_pressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>    
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <item android:top="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_pressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unchecked" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_pressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>    
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
           <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_shadow" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unpressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_checked" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unpressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
           <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_shadow" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unpressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unchecked" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="4dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/toggle_button_unpressed" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

I haven't checked it so I don't know if it works. Please let me know if I made any errors.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I can see that the xml works :)

Comment: Even if this worked, I must confess I don't understand what is happening. Can you please elaborate the way layer-list works? If for example, I want to put a stroke, how will I do that?

Comment: In the layer-list, the item furthest down the list shows on top. It shows several rectangles on top of each other. Android drawables are a little tricky as if you specify a `size` with height and width you are forced with the drawable only ever being that size. This is why I am offsetting the rectangle shapes by giving them offsets from the edge of the view like `android:bottom="4dp"`. To add a stroke either: (i) draw two rectangles on top of each other, the first of the stroke color and the second of the fill color, (ii) add a stroke property to a shape to draw a stroke all the way around it.