# How to show the text on a ImageButton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an `ImageButton` and I want to show a text and an image on it. But when I try on emulator:

```
<ImageButton 
    android:text="OK" 
    android:id="@+id/buttonok" 
    android:src="@drawable/buttonok"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I get the image but without the text. How can I show the text? Please help me!

Answer (score 300, accepted):

As you can't use `android:text` I recommend you to use a normal button and use one of the compound drawables. For instance:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/buttonok" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonok"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

You can put the drawable wherever you want by using: `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`, `drawableLeft` or `drawableRight`.

**UPDATE**

For a button this too works pretty fine. Putting `android:background` is fine!

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_left_menu_login"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
    android:text="@string/login_string" />
```

I just had this issue and is working perfectly.

Comment: This option works best, unless you need some sort of crazy looking button layout, like an image sandwhiched by two textviews.  I originally tried a layout object defined as widget.button, then put an imageview and a textview in it, but after profiling that, and the Button layout above, I saved nearly 30% in measure time, 50% in layout time, and 15-20% in Draw time on my FramLayout, and went from 38 objects down to 26.    that's a pretty substantial savings.

Comment: What's the difference between the drawableTop, bottom etc.?

Comment: @shim drawableTop will place the drawable at the top of the button, drawableRight at the bottom, etc.

Comment: Is there any way to put drawableLeft programmatically?

Comment: @RenanBandeira yes, uset `setCompoundDrawables*()` methods

Comment: How can I scale the image to fit the button? Or it would automatically adjust the image to fit with the button.

Comment: Same question as @Stallman, how to fit the image with the button, and set it to the left?

Comment: Use `android:drawableStart` in combination with  `android:drawableLeft` so you can support RTL layout as well. ( `android:drawableStart` was introduced only in API 17 so if you want to support older versions, you still need to provide a fallback to `android:drawableLeft` )

Comment: if you want to use VECTOR (srcCompat) as an drawable (drawableLeft, drawableRight and so on), you have to override Button class, otherwise app will crash on api below 19 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/40250753/2163045

Comment: @EvanR. I don't think having an image and text to be placed at the center, next to each other is "crazy". This solution places an icon at the start of the button and aligns text in the middle. Craziness is Android core team not giving shit about such s simple component

Answer (score 69):

It is technically possible to put a caption on an `ImageButton` if you really want to do it. Just put a `TextView` over the `ImageButton` using `FrameLayout`. Just remember to not make the `Textview` clickable.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_x"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/button_graphic" >
    </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="TEST TEST" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This not seem to work on Lollipop though works perfectly on others.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the text is not affected by the button state (disabled etc.)... unless you do that manually.

Answer (score 17):

Guys I need to develop the setting and logout button, I used the below code.
[image]

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLogout"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/logout" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `android:text` is not an argument accepted by `ImageButton`
but, If you're trying to get a button with a specified background (not android default) use the `android:background` xml attribute, or declare it from the class with `.setBackground();`

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by putting the `ImageButton` and `TextView` inside a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation. Works great!

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linLayout"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/camera_ibtn"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/take_pic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `LinearLayout` instead of using `Button` it's an arrangement i used in my app

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@color/mainColor"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cv"
            android:textColor="@color/offBack"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/cartyCv"
            android:textColor="@color/offBack"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great solution! onClick works perfectly on LinearLayout too. Don't see a reason why we should use a Button or ImageButton

Answer (score 3):

you can use a regular `Button` and the android:drawableTop attribute (or left, right, bottom) instead.

Comment: I found this answer to me the quickest and most effective solution for adding an image such as an icon next to button text

Answer (score 2):

Best way:

```
<Button 
android:text="OK" 
android:id="@+id/buttonok" 
android:background="@drawable/buttonok"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be any different to what the OP originally tried.

Comment: Sorry, i mistake my code. Wasn´t ImageButton, was just Button.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a nice circle example:

`drawable/circle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="#ff87cefa"/>

    <size
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
</shape>
```

And then the button in your xml file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    android:text="OK"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWj0j.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_line1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_mute"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_mute"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_keypad"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_dialpad"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_speaker"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_speaker"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_gray"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttons_line1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="mute"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Grey"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="keypad"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Grey"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="speaker"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/Grey"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Best way to show `Text` on `button`(with image)

[image: example of text on button with image background]

**Your Question**: How to show `text` on `imagebutton`?

**Answer**: You can not display `text` with `imageButton`. Method that tell in *Accepted answer* also not work.

because

If you use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonok"` then you can not set `drawable` in `center` of `button`.

If you use `android:background="@drawable/button_bg"` then `color` of your `drawable` will be changed.

In android world there are thousands of option to do this. But here i provide best alternate according to my point of view. (see below)

> ### Solution: Use `cardView` with `LinearLayout`

Your `drawable/image` use in `LinearLayout` because it shows in center. And with help of `textView` you can set `text` on this. We makes `cardView` background to `transparent`.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/your_selected_image"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Happy Coding"
                        android:textSize="33sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        >
                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

here i explain some terms:

`app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"` for make transparent background of `cardView`

`app:cardElevation="0dp"` for hide evelation lines around `cardView`

`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` its provide actual size of `cardView`. Always use this when you use `cardView`

set your `image/drawable` in `LinearLayout` as a background.

Sorry, for my Bad English.

### Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageButton` can't have `text` (or, at least, `android:text` isn't listed in its attributes).

The Trick is:

It looks like you need to use `Button` (and look at `drawableTop` or `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,int,int,int))`.