# I can not see text on the Image button?

Tags: android, text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show the text on a ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457030/how-to-show-the-text-on-a-imagebutton)

what is wrong with the xml, I can not see my text on the button

```
    <ImageButton
    android1:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android1:contentDescription="@string/empty"
    android1:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android1:src="@drawable/blue_button"
    android1:background="@null"
    android1:text = "@string/here_and_now"
    android1:textColor="@string/black_color"
    android1:gravity="center"
   />
```

Comment: y your using android1 ? its android: not android1

Comment: ok, but android1 works me  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="match_parent"
    android1:background="@color/white"
    android1:gravity="top" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use `android:text`for the ImageButton. so just use a button and set background for it.

For example:

```
<Button 
   android1:id="@+id/btnShowLocation"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android1:text = "@string/here_and_now"
   android:background="@drawable/blue_button"/>
```

Comment: why we cant use android:text ?.. We can !

Comment: because there is no attribute text for the image button by default.to check click [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457030/how-to-show-the-text-on-a-imagebutton got it from here :)

Comment: But I want to text to be in center of the button. drawableTop left are useless for me!!

Comment: Then don't give any of these attributes. Just define text:"OK". It'll show in the center.

Comment: Just set the background for the button and give the text.

Comment: drawableTop, drawableLeft are giving me horrible results, as my if i use drawableTop, text goes down, If i use drawableLeft, text goes right.

Comment: so instead of drawble use background

Comment: Ram kiran, I wish I can award you 100 points on it, you reply really helped me.. this is what i was trying to figure out, I was looking to center the text and no one understood me. thanks buddy. Actually, it is quiet easy in Flash and iphone, I am new to android and eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find android:text property under ImageButton tag.

You should rather use a button and use "background" property to put an image on a button.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/friendsListButton" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/friendsListScreen" android:background="@drawable/blue_button"/>
```

If you want an image on the button, just define it as above.

Comment: drawableTop, drawableLeft are giving me horrible results, as my if i use drawableTop, text goes down, If i use drawableLeft, text goes right..

Comment: So just don't give any drawableTop or anything. Just define the button as in my answer. Do you want an image on button or just text?

Comment: I used  background instead of drawable. and got the required result.