# Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class ImageButton, Resource NotFoundException, XmlPullParserException

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, android-vectordrawable, inflate-exception, tokbox

In API: 19 Iam facing this Inflate Exception but Iam using AppCompatDrawableManager which supports as vector drawables in API:19

three Exceptions 
1. Error in Inflate Image button
2. Resources$NotFoundException File res/drawable/bckg_icon.xml from drawable resource
3. org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector

I have tried to decerese the ImageButton drawable src which four formats(hdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi etc) 
my Implementation :
xml File which is fragmnet xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layoutPreviewActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/previewFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
         android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:text="00:00"
         android:id="@+id/timeduration"
         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/localVideo"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginRight="14.1dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/call"
         android:background="@drawable/bckg_icon"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:src="@drawable/video_icon" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/call"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:background="@drawable/initiate_call_button"
         android:clickable="true"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/start_call" />

     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/localAudio"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="14.1dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/call"
         android:background="@drawable/bckg_icon"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/mic_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Fragment java class those drawables implementation :

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_actionbar_fragment, container, false);
    mAudioBtn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.localAudio);
    mVideoBtn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.localVideo);
    mCallBtn = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.call);
    timdura= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeduration); 
    c=mActivity;
    booking_id=mActivity.bookingId;
    drawableStartCall = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(mActivity,R.drawable.initiate_call_button);
    drawableEndCall =AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(mActivity,R.drawable.end_call_button);
    drawableBckBtn = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(mActivity,R.drawable.bckg_icon);
```

My logCat details:

```
   I/com. .MainActivity: OnAttach PreviewControlFragment
   I/com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor.MainActivity: OnCreate PreviewControlFragment
   D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a22cf8)
   W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred

   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor/com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class ImageButton
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                  at com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor.ui.PreviewControlFragment.onCreateView(PreviewControlFragment.java:165)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5353)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/bckg_icon.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005c
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2170)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
                                                                                  at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:118)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                  at com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor.ui.PreviewControlFragment.onCreateView(PreviewControlFragment.java:165) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607) 
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174) 
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5353) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                               Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binar
```

I have tried from StackOverflow some similar Question not working

1. to reduce the images sizes ,

2.use app:srcCompat instead of android:src attribute in XML

problem only in API:19 lower DPI devices how to Handle these type of Exceptions

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while but I think that you are using a `VectorDrawable` as background of your `ImageButton` in here:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/localVideo"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_width"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_height"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:layout_marginRight="14.1dp"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/call"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"
     android:src="@drawable/video_icon"
     android:background="@drawable/bckg_icon />"   <!-- <- here is your problem -->
```

I figured out that using `VectorDrawable` as background of `TextView`, `EditText`, `Button`, `ImageButton`, etc using `android:background="..."` cause a crash on API 19 and before, Because `android:background` on older devices is using old APIs and when android tries to inflate your `VectorDrawable` it can not parse it and crashes. Note that when you are using `app:srcCompat` as the source image of your `ImageView` you are using Compat library and there is no problem.
For fixing this you can use one of 3 methods:

1. Use an `ImageView` behind your view and set its `app:srcCompat` to your `VectorDrawable`
2. Use a custom widget that loads `VectorDrawable` [using Compat library in runtime and sets the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636)
3. Use [alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) to set background of your `View` to your `VectorDrawable` in API 21 and above and set it to a `BitmapDrawable` (png file for example) in lower APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Once I had faced same issue, You can try anyone of the following methods :

- Use .png or .jpeg instead of xml, and make sure the drawables are copied to drawable folder ( sometime it copies to drawable(v21) folder and then these images will not be available for API below 21).
- Check the same thing for .xml drawables, in which directory it is kept.(You can view directory structure by changing view from Android to Project[image: You can see this image]
- Use srcCompat instead of src in xml files. You may need to declare

  compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'

Comment: Option 1. i have used png for android:srcCompact and background xml resource which are vector drawables how can i convert into  png or jpeg. Option2 all the xml files in drawable folder and png's in drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,-xhdpi,-xxhdpi,-xxxhdpi folders which mean drawable. Option 3 i have tried same error is comming