# Resources$NotFoundException while setting drawable as android:drawableLeft in textView in kitkat

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm getting an error in pre-lollipop devices. The drawable is vector drawable and I'm using many vector drawables in my app. Those vector drawable which has been set on ImageView's src or background, working fine. But setting drawableLeft with textview throws exception. Here is the stacktrace-

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_place_black_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200ee
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                              at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:840)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:62)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:58)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                              at com.overtatech.TotalTasty.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Comment: @Ninja  I saw the post and looks like the same my problem. I think I got my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create drawable file `ic_place_black_24dp.xml` and paste below code;

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,2C8.13,2 5,5.13 5,9c0,5.25 7,13 7,13s7,-7.75 7,-13c0,-3.87 -3.13,-7 -7,-7zM12,11.5c-1.38,0 -2.5,-1.12 -2.5,-2.5s1.12,-2.5 2.5,-2.5 2.5,1.12 2.5,2.5 -1.12,2.5 -2.5,2.5z"/>
```