# Why Inflact Exception is thrown while using vector drable in xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used vector drawable in an `ImageView` in `android`.

here is my code:

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:id="@+id/titleImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />
```

when running the app in `API19` I got these error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.nuvo.driver, PID: 4303
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.nuvo.driver/com.nuvo.driver.SignUp_Activity_}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error
>   inflating class ImageButton

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: show your `ImageButton` code

Comment: `Error inflating class ImageButton`  It's an `ImageButton` issue, not `ImageView`. Have you got some `ImageButton` in your view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using this code in build.gradle file:

```
android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

i think you are using vector drawable for a button or textview or ...
this act makes exception on your app for android below 5.
if my guess is true use this structure:
[Is it possible to use VectorDrawable in Buttons and TextViews using android:DrawableRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do two option to solve that :

1. use android:src in place of app:srcCompat 
   or
2. use vectore dwable you have to change 
   `android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in build.gridle file

Comment: please check  ( Like ) the ans.