# How to use VectorDrawable in Android <selector>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to use VectorDrawable for Radio toggle button, but I got '**invalid drawable tag vector**' error in API level 17 device.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_list_off" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

I'm using this in a fragment, and I set the setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled to true in Activity which wraps the fragment.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
```

Also, I set the

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

in build.gradle

And this is the view xml,

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/list_view_type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/grid_btn_toggle"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/list_btn_toggle"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="" />
</RadioGroup>
```

This is the one of the vector images content

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="21.0"
    android:viewportWidth="21.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M2.5,0L2.5,0A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,5 2.5L5,2.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 5L2.5,5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,0 2.5L0,2.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 0z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M2.5,8L2.5,8A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,5 10.5L5,10.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 13L2.5,13A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,0 10.5L0,10.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 8z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M2.5,16L2.5,16A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,5 18.5L5,18.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 21L2.5,21A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,0 18.5L0,18.5A2.5,2.5 0,0 1,2.5 16z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M7,1.455L20,1.455a1,1 0,0 1,1 1L21,2.455a1,1 0,0 1,-1 1L7,3.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 3.455L7,1.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 1.455Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M7,9.455L20,9.455a1,1 0,0 1,1 1L21,10.455a1,1 0,0 1,-1 1L7,11.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 11.455L7,9.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 9.455Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#c3c3c3" android:pathData="M7,17.455L20,17.455a1,1 0,0 1,1 1L21,18.455a1,1 0,0 1,-1 1L7,19.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 19.455L7,17.455A0,0 0,0 1,7 17.455Z"/>
</vector>
```

Is there any way I can use the VectorDrawable in android:drawable in the selector for API level 16 or 17?

Build.grade contents,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jp.dandoli.dandoliworks"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.0-rc2"

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1"

    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"

    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: Please, add build.gradle file

Comment: i think removing AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true) from your code'll work for you.

Comment: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88 Check this. That might help you

Comment: @savepopulation I tried but still no luck

Comment: @fisher3421 I update my question for your review, could you please take 
 a look?

Comment: so you can try to set as button as mentioned in medium article above. android:button="@drawable/state_list_icon"

Comment: @savepopulation Yes I tried but still I got 'invalid drawable tag vector' error

Comment: @Expertwannabe I've read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw And I think you can do it only programmatically

Comment: @Expertwannabe Did you fix this problem? I face it right now.

Answer (score 0):

use `animated-selector`

example

https://github.com/alexjlockwood/adp-delightful-details

https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html

create `animated-vector` file with this tool

https://shapeshifter.design/

Answer (score 0):

You should apply your custom `Drawable` to the `android:button` attribute instead of `android:background`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton#attr_android:button