# Android app unfortunately stopped caused by android:drawableBottom

Tags: android

I have a **android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton** in my layout XML. My app works correctly on Android SDK 21 but it, unfortunately, stopped in Android SDK 16 (my minSDKVersion in AndroidManifest.xml is 16).
My **AppCompatButton** is this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_navigate_next" />
```

and error is this:

```
11-07 22:20:36.774 3300-3300/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2071)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #97: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                 at com.virascience.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.virascience.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_navigate_next.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02007d
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.virascience.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:886)
                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:822)
                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634) 
                                                 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                 at com.virascience.app.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:90) 
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2096) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why this problem occurs and How can resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

you might have separated your drawable folders to based on version/screen_size
make sure your drawable exist for all versions or if you don't have one simply put a copy of it in your base "drawable" folder

`android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_navigate_next"`

***ic_navigate_next*** must be in all drawable folders or one generic one in main **drawable**

see if it helps?

Answer (score 0):

If your drawable is a vector drawable then that might be it.
See:
Here's [a link] ([Is it possible to use VectorDrawable in Buttons and TextViews using android:DrawableRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw))!