# Unable to add drawable start with SVG to TextView for Android API lowers that 21

Tags: android, android-layout, vector, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to use drawable in textView like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/svg_ic_profile_logout"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/svg_ic_profile_logout"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick="@{viewModel.onLogoutClick}"
    android:text="@string/profile_logout"/>
```

but the icon I using is SVG, it works perfectly fine for API > 21 but got a crash for API level lower than 21.

Comment: Someone found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Comment: Follow this StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  **vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true** in you app level  build.gradle as follows:

```
  //For Gradle Plugin 2.0+
 android {
   defaultConfig {
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
 }
```

Refer to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html).

Comment: I've added, also try to use AppCompatTextView but won't work

Comment: @theerasantonthongkam you are using a real device or emulator ?

Comment: I use real device

Comment: share your crash log

Comment: Solved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Comment: @theerasantonthongkam, what solution helped you?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw

Answer (score 0):

1. If your activity extends `FragmentActivity`, extend `AppCompatActivity`.
2. If you have an exception: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class TextView` having `TextView` with `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_svg_image"`, then follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146570/2914140.

Set SVG support as described there and wrap your SVG image in `selector` or `layer-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_svg_image" />
</selector>
```

Then change to `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/svg_image_selector"`, where `svg_image_selector` is an XML created above.