# Android App Crashes while rendering vector asset on API 19 works fine on API above 20

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, xml-drawable

App Crashes while starting MyActivity on Android API level 19 with following code and stack trace.
This works fine on Android API level 21 and above.

Vector Asset : **ic_warning_white_24px.xml**

**activity_my.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    tools:context="MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Hint" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }
}
```

also added following in my **build.gradle**

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

> Process: MyPackage, PID: 16398 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity ComponentInfo{MyPackage/MyActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error
>   inflating class   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>   at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>   at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/ic_warning_white_24px.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f080172  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)  at
>
> android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)  at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:814)  at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:71)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:67)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>   at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  Caused by:
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0:
>   invalid drawable tag vector  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
>   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)  at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:814)   at
>   android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:71) 
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:67) 
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>   at MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:43)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)  
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

**Also tried few things**

```
static
{
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use vector drawables for `drawableLeft, drawableRight`. Sorry.

also try

```
        app:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
        app:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
```

instead of

```
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_warning_white_24px"
```

(app vs android)

If AppCompatButton has implemented it, you will be able to use it this way.

see this question [Is it possible to use VectorDrawable in Buttons and TextViews using android:DrawableRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35761636/3904645)

See this awesome article about vectors [AppCompat — Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Comment: getting Error:error: attribute mypackage:drawableEnd' not found.

Comment: This means that AppCompatButton has not implemented it yet. So you have to find acceptable work around in the question i linked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My solution was to add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` to

1) Application on create method **(if you've)**:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

2) **OR** to you specific Acticivity `onCreate()`:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
}
```