# when i use svg image file in editText right drawlble, app crashed in lower than api 21

Tags: android, svg

my code is simple in xml file:

`android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_mobile"`

NOTE: im readed this question but i want find The easier the solution [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761636/is-it-possible-to-use-vectordrawable-in-buttons-and-textviews-using-androiddraw)

thanks

Comment: What question? Did you enable the vector support library?

Comment: i use this version "support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0" and my code correctly work in android version 5 and higher