# Android shape button stripped

Tags: android, button

I want to build a button with 3 different color in the background like the attached image, and I have no idea how to do that with shapes

[image]

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Why not using a image as backgorund?

Comment: u want button on above this bg?

Comment: @LucaNicolett with image I have to adapt it to each screen, shape are better for performances

Comment: @mitesh viradiya  Yes i want a  button above

Comment: can u post your UI image what u really want

Comment: You can use gradients, but that whould looks different from that image

Comment: @mitesh viradiya it's the same image as the post, there is just a centered text, and the whole image is a button

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton and use above image as background of that button:

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/YOUR_BTN_IMG"/>
```

Comment: *how to do that with shapes*

Comment: Thank you Drv, but I want to do it with shape

Answer (score 0):

1st make a xml file in drawable folder with bg1 name and put this code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#4CAF50"
        android:endColor="#2E7D32"
        android:startColor="#b5e7b7"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

than where ever you want it use like

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/bg1"/>
```

here u change angle,start end and center color as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you, In fact I don't want to use gradient, I need only 3 colors, maybe i need to create 3 shapes, but i don't know how make them diagonal

Comment: just make angle 45 or 135 so it become diagonal

Comment: I have already tried, it gives many gradient color without stripes, I only need 3 stripped color, nothing between

Comment: than i think you have to use 9-patch image so that it can be expand as per your requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457030/how-to-show-the-text-on-a-imagebutton use this link than inform me its work or not

Comment: I can't see difference between 9-path image and an normal image with different size, it still an image isn't ?