# How to make a button like in a Menu (OptionMenuItem)?

Tags: android, button, menu

There is a (Menu menu) which I've already filled with MenuItems. There is also custom dialog, which I want to use instead of standart OptionMenu. I decided to use Button instead of ItemMenuView in it.

So I fill my custom dialog with Buttons, add the icon and the text of MenuItem to every Button and as a result get a completly awful 'Menu'.

My question is, describe please step by step how to make a common Button (or not a Button) looks like a common MenuItemView.

Thaks in advance!

Comment: trying to adopt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton/3734246#3734246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's turned up pretty enough for me:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:id="@+id/menu_btn1"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_btn1"
        />
```

where **drawable/custom_button** I left empty and **drawable/menu_btn1** represents common **selector** with pressed/enadled states

Comment: hey i want to make every item in my ListView look like a button should this code help me, ? I would've tried it out but i dont understand where to put this.. is this a drawable xml ?