# How to create button with image & text

Tags: android, imageview

Friends,

I want to display a button in android like mentioned in screenshot.

Could anyone guide me through how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) which you can use for that.

But I'm not sure how to make the Text on the button look like the Text in your screenshot. I would simply create the image with the text and then use it for the `ImageButton`.

Comment: If you have images with text on them, then maintaining and localizing them becomes a hassle.

Comment: You can create Images for every supported language and if those images are just for some buttons, the shouldn't be to large.

Answer (score 3):

Use a normal Butto with `drawableLeft` attribute. See my sample code:

```
<Button android:layout_width="100dip" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_refresh"
    android:id="@+id/btn_refresh" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use 9-patch fot background. You can specify padding area there (bottom and right lines), so background will be stretchable while text will not cover image. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/refresh"
android:text="Refresh"/>
```