# Android images and text in single view

Tags: android

I want to display text ,images in single View .
kindly help me also 
 i want to give src of image from my class instead of xml kindly help 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Button` for this

```
Button b=new Button(this);
b.setText(" Button");     
b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_call), null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at TextView here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

look for android:drawableLeft,android:drawableRight,android:drawbleTop,android:drawbleBottom

to set drawable from class...look for setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use a normal button with [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft) / [drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableRight) / [drawableTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop) / [drawableBotton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom) attribute.

See a sample here: [How to create button with image & text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253488/how-to-create-button-with-image-text)