# How can i create a BUTTON with image and text?

Tags: image, button, textview, imagebutton

I want to create a button or image button and It will contain icon and text. The icon will locate to left side  and text will located center a button.

Comment: sorry! Android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples if you search further. For instance:

[Button with text AND an image (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793293/button-with-text-and-an-image-android)

[Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:text="Drawable\nleft"/>
```

Here the answer :)