# How can I scale the background of a button?

Tags: android, button, background, scale

I have the following button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonok"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_no_save"
android:text="OK" />
```

Its appearence is:

[image]

How can I scale down my drawable and show a small arrow?

Answer (score 9):

You could use an `ImageButton` and try `android:scaleType`

[ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: I need the "OK" text so I can not use ImageButton.

Answer (score 4):

I don't hink you can from xml. There's no xml attribute that can do scaling for buttons. You can do it programatically though, in the following way :

```
Bitmap originalBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
Bitmap scaledBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
txt.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bit));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could scale down the actual graphic that the drawable points to.

Comment: How about using a ScaleDrawable?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` then it seems to me that the best way to do it is to create your own component.
You can extend `RelativeLayout` and put `ImageView` into it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I did something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="XXXXXXX"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```