# Button and image with txt

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I want to create button where I have icon and text. This is what I created:

[image]

This is xml:

> ```
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/call_button"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="0dp"
>           android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>             android:background="@drawable/button"
>             android:layout_weight="40" 
>             android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
>             android:text="Call"
>             android:textColor="@color/white"
>             />
> ```

How I can move this phone icon closer text?

Comment: You have to use Drawable - Nine-patch (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: Check your button image width. Does it has transparent pixels in the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may guide you for arrangements,

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html

Code:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_btn_test"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_icon_test"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
        android:paddingTop="32sp"
        android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
        android:text="this is text"></Button>
```

ref from: [Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)

Refer here also: http://www.mokasocial.com/2010/04/create-a-button-with-an-image-and-text-android/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try providing paddingLeft attribute.

```
<Button android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="hello" />
```

It helped me to move the Drawable towards the Text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot set the compound drawable's position, but you may add some transparent pixels arround your image and that should do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Create an image as you like and put it in to the drawable folder. Create an image view and set that image, then you can set the onclick event to that image.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
   // your code here
}
});
```