# Set the side of an image when using android:drawable____ in a button

Tags: android, image, button, drawable

Simple question here : I am customizing some buttons, placing an icon next to my text via android:drawableLeft or Right, but I can't seem to find how to define the size with accuracy. My image happen to be too big and go out of the shape of my button.

Oh, and while I am at it: android:drawableLeft allows to put an image on the left of the text, but how to decide the distance FROM the text ? In my case, it automatically goes to the extreme left of my button while my text is centered. The result is everything but nice !

Thanks !

Comment: you can apply padding to your view

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to start from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton).

> but how to decide the distance FROM the text ?

Here you have an answer:

> android:drawablePadding can be used to specify the amount of padding between the image and button text.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom)

Answer (score 1):

i guess this will do the trick

use `android:drawablePadding` in conjunction with `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` to force the text and drawable inward towards the center of the button...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define the accuracy size of the drawable, You should use Java code instead of android:drawableLeft

```
  Drawable dw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic);
  dw.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100); // set the size of the drawable to 100*100

  button.setCompoundDrawables(dw, null, null, null);
```

because of

```
 android:drawableLeft // equals with  setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds
```

and

```
 android:drawablePadding // this used to control the padding between the text and drawable
```