# Custom action icon on android devices

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, android

I am developing custom menu item by calling action layout, but when i am taping that action menu that pressing color is not applying total height giving some top and bottom margin.

Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView 
        android:minWidth="56dp"
        android:id="@+id/voicemailNotificationCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ab_pressedicon_bgcolor"
        android:contentDescription="@string/voicemailnotification"
        android:src="@drawable/ab_voicemail"> 
     </ImageView>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vmNotificationTextCounter"
        android:text="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/voicemailNotificationCounter"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_alertbg"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your icon a nine-patch?

Comment: No it is not nine-patch image it is just normal action bar icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're not using an ImageButton.

Combining an image with text [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734246/320111) with an ImageButton. You can even independently adjust the text and the image inside that ImageButton.

Hopefully, an ImageButton will work inside an action menu, I haven't actually tested that part yet.

Comment: @Rayani, By the way, if you find an answer most useful to you, marking it accepted is also a good way of saying thank you for it. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/151788 Also, don't discount the use of 9-patch, even if you find it isn't normally used inside of action menus. Using a 9-patch with match_parent and some tweaking inside your existing code would probably have worked as well (without the need of an ImageButton).