# How to use different png textless buttons for different languages in android?

Tags: android, button, multilingual

I have a set of textless PNG buttons that I did adding the text in photoshop in English and in Spanish, I don't have the option to use the string file cause the text is already added in Photoshop. How do I use the spanish buttons if the user selects spanish language??.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as Spanish strings. You can use `drawable-en` and `drawable-es` same way as for strings - `values-en`, `values-es`. Put image for English into `drawable-en`, and for Spanish - into `drawable-es`

Comment: Thanks, both answers were good but I'll take this one cause I don't have many images as 2Dee suggested. Just one more question, If I have the drawable-en and drawable-es in two sepparate folders, what's going to happen if someone from other place than those two enters the app, should I keep a neutral drawable folder to provide the default english images  to these people?

Comment: @JAF   You'll need the default image placed into `drawable` folder. Without any `-en` or `-es`

Answer (score 1):

> PNG buttons that I did adding the text in photoshop

--> that's your main problem, trying to circumvent it will probably prove to be less efficient than using the framework's built-in system to produce buttons with text and images ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton) discusses how to do that).  But if you can't, you can probably use the system's Locale to determine the language of the user, like so :

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
// this will return "en" for english
```

Comment: The thing is that I did a button with two states that I control with an XML when the user clicks on it and I needed the blending effect on the text that only photoshop gives me.....Thanks anyway for the function, really useful

Comment: De nada, I hope it will prove useful nonetheless. You could try Vlad Matvienko's solution if you don't have too many images (duplicating images in several folders will make your apk size grow).