# Android add text in a drawable button

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

How can I add text in a drawable image button without adding text with classic way at main xml file with the command "android:text="test", but I want to add the text of the image button in the drawable xml (code 2).

Code 1 - main.xml:

```
     <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/start_off"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:background="@null"/>
```

Code 2 - drawable xml button:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape
        android:shape="oval">

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#990000"
            android:endColor="#ff0000"
            />

        <corners
            android:radius="4dp"
            />

        <size
            android:width="120dp"
            android:height="120dp"
            />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Beacuse I use this drawbale code to update via USB the state of a button (if it is on or no) and I can only use image button.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a button and have the drawable be the background? Here is a good link to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)