# How to combine text and image button in android?

Tags: android, button

I want to make button with text and image like this

[image]

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/mohit008/Android-List-View)

Comment: Those look like preferences rather than buttons.

Comment: Looks like a TextView with a **compound drawable** on the left.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `drawable_left` . assign your icons to your widget like this :

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_drawable"
            android:text="@string/your_text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:drawablePadding="5sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Button">
</Button>
```

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyLl.png)

see below link

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZyLl.png](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3734246/5901444)