# How to import my own designed widget(like button, textfield) in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have designed a Text Field through illustrator and converted in `.png` file and I want to use it in android studio. How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with xmls you can add :

`android:background="@drawable/myResouce"`

You can also change it from the code doing:

```
YourTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myResouce);
```

where drawable is the folder , where you will have your PNG file

**And , if you want to make your OWN widget , you might want to check this below link :**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm